# Insertar enlace que me dirija a un enlace determinado

Tags: html

Tengo el siguiente código que he obtenido creando mi primera página web y me ha surgido la siguiente duda a la hora de insertar un enlace a cada una de las temperaturas de cada mes, que al hacer click en ellas me dirija a un gráfico determinado de Google.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
Página Web
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Temperatura media por meses</h1>
<h2>Enero</h2>
<h3>13º/7º</h3>
<h2>Febrero</h2>
<h3>13º/8º</h3>
<h2>Marzo</h2>
<h3>14º/8º</h3>
<h2>Abril</h2>
<h3>15º/9º</h3>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar la etiqueta `<a>`, es para representar texto como un enlace a un recurso en la web, haciendo uso del atributo href puedes colocar la direccion al recurso que quieres ir segun el enlace, en tu caso pondrias el link al grafico de google.

Ejemplo:

```html
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Ir a youtube</a>
```

Puedes anidar elementos en HTML de manera que tus encabezados tengan como contenido otro elemento. en este caso colocarías el elemento  dentro de tus